# ElasticSearch In Kubernetes failed to start: "max number of threads [1024] for user [elasticsearch] is too low, increase to at least [4096]"

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, ulimit

I am trying to deploy the elasticsearch (7.17.9) using the HELM chart in kubernetes. The POD's went on error and below is the message found in the logs

"bootstrap check failure [1] of [2]: max number of threads [1024] for user [elasticsearch] is too low, increase to at least [4096]"

Most of the blogs suggest to modify the docker daemon config file in the worker nodes. Is there any way to set the ulimit for this specific POD without modifying the worker node settings?

Values.yaml file content

```
---
clusterName: "elasticsearch"
nodeGroup: "master"
namespaceName: "elasticsearch"

# The service that non master groups will try to connect to when joining the cluster
# This should be set to clusterName + "-" + nodeGroup for your master group
masterService: ""

# Elasticsearch roles that will be applied to this nodeGroup
# These will be set as environment variables. E.g. node.roles=master
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#node-roles
roles:
  - master
  - data
  - data_content
#  - data_hot
#  - data_warm
#  - data_cold
#  - ingest
#  - ml
#  - remote_cluster_client
#  - transform

replicas: 3
minimumMasterNodes: 2

esMajorVersion: "7"

# Allows you to add any config files in /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/
# such as elasticsearch.yml and log4j2.properties
esConfig: {}
#  elasticsearch.yml: |
#    key:
#      nestedkey: value
#  log4j2.properties: |
#    key = value

createCert: false

esJvmOptions: {}
#  processors.options: |
#    -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=3

# Extra environment variables to append to this nodeGroup
# This will be appended to the current 'env:' key. You can use any of the kubernetes env
# syntax here
extraEnvs:
  - name: xpack.security.enabled
    value: 'false'
#  - name: MY_ENVIRONMENT_VAR
#    value: the_value_goes_here

# Allows you to load environment variables from kubernetes secret or config map
envFrom: []
# - secretRef:
#     name: env-secret
# - configMapRef:
#     name: config-map

# Disable it to use your own elastic-credential Secret.
secret:
  enabled: true
  password: "" # generated randomly if not defined

# A list of secrets and their paths to mount inside the pod
# This is useful for mounting certificates for security and for mounting
# the X-Pack license
secretMounts: []
#  - name: elastic-certificates
#    secretName: elastic-certificates
#    path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
#    defaultMode: 0755

hostAliases: []
#- ip: "127.0.0.1"
#  hostnames:
#  - "foo.local"
#  - "bar.local"

image: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch"
imageTag: "7.17.9"
imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"

podAnnotations: {}
# iam.amazonaws.com/role: es-cluster

# additionals labels
labels: {}

esJavaOpts: "" # example: "-Xmx1g -Xms1g"

resources:
  requests:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "2Gi"
  limits:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "2Gi"

initResources: {}
# limits:
#   cpu: "25m"
#   # memory: "128Mi"
# requests:
#   cpu: "25m"
#   memory: "128Mi"

networkHost: "0.0.0.0"

volumeClaimTemplate:
  accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi

rbac:
  create: false
  serviceAccountAnnotations: {}
  serviceAccountName: ""
  automountToken: true

podSecurityPolicy:
  create: false
  name: ""
  spec:
    privileged: true
    fsGroup:
      rule: RunAsAny
    runAsUser:
      rule: RunAsAny
    seLinux:
      rule: RunAsAny
    supplementalGroups:
      rule: RunAsAny
    volumes:
      - secret
      - configMap
      - persistentVolumeClaim
      - emptyDir

persistence:
  enabled: true
  labels:
    # Add default labels for the volumeClaimTemplate of the StatefulSet
    enabled: false
  annotations: {}

extraVolumes: []
# - name: extras
#   emptyDir: {}

extraVolumeMounts: []
# - name: extras
#   mountPath: /usr/share/extras
#   readOnly: true

extraContainers: []
# - name: do-something
#   image: busybox
#   command: ['do', 'something']

extraInitContainers: []
# - name: do-something
#   image: busybox
#   command: ['do', 'something']

# This is the PriorityClass settings as defined in
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/#priorityclass
priorityClassName: ""

# By default this will make sure two pods don't end up on the same node
# Changing this to a region would allow you to spread pods across regions
antiAffinityTopologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"

# Hard means that by default pods will only be scheduled if there are enough nodes for them
# and that they will never end up on the same node. Setting this to soft will do this "best effort"
antiAffinity: "hard"

# This is the node affinity settings as defined in
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity-beta-feature
nodeAffinity: {}

# The default is to deploy all pods serially. By setting this to parallel all pods are started at
# the same time when bootstrapping the cluster
podManagementPolicy: "Parallel"

# The environment variables injected by service links are not used, but can lead to slow Elasticsearch boot times when
# there are many services in the current namespace.
# If you experience slow pod startups you probably want to set this to `false`.
enableServiceLinks: true

protocol: https
httpPort: 9200
transportPort: 9300

service:
  enabled: true
  labels: {}
  labelsHeadless: {}
  type: ClusterIP
  # Consider that all endpoints are considered "ready" even if the Pods themselves are not
  # https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/service-resources/service-v1/#ServiceSpec
  publishNotReadyAddresses: false
  nodePort: ""
  annotations: {}
  httpPortName: http
  transportPortName: transport
  loadBalancerIP: ""
  loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
  externalTrafficPolicy: ""

updateStrategy: RollingUpdate

# This is the max unavailable setting for the pod disruption budget
# The default value of 1 will make sure that kubernetes won't allow more than 1
# of your pods to be unavailable during maintenance
maxUnavailable: 1

podSecurityContext:
  fsGroup: 1000
  runAsUser: 1000

securityContext:
  capabilities:
    drop:
      - ALL
  # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  runAsNonRoot: true
  runAsUser: 1000

# How long to wait for elasticsearch to stop gracefully
terminationGracePeriod: 120

sysctlVmMaxMapCount: 262144

readinessProbe:
  failureThreshold: 3
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
  successThreshold: 3
  timeoutSeconds: 5

# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html#request-params wait_for_status
clusterHealthCheckParams: "wait_for_status=green&timeout=1s"

## Use an alternate scheduler.
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-multiple-schedulers/
##
schedulerName: ""

imagePullSecrets: []
nodeSelector: {}
tolerations:
  - key: "processor"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "true"
    effect: "NoSchedule"

# Enabling this will publicly expose your Elasticsearch instance.
# Only enable this if you have security enabled on your cluster
ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
  # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  className: "nginx"
  pathtype: ImplementationSpecific
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths:
        - path: /
  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local

nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""
healthNameOverride: ""

lifecycle: {}
# preStop:
#   exec:
#     command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello from the postStart handler > /usr/share/message"]
# postStart:
#   exec:
#     command:
#       - bash
#       - -c
#       - |
#         #!/bin/bash
#         # Add a template to adjust number of shards/replicas
#         TEMPLATE_NAME=my_template
#         INDEX_PATTERN="logstash-*"
#         SHARD_COUNT=8
#         REPLICA_COUNT=1
#         ES_URL=http://localhost:9200
#         while [[ "$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' $ES_URL)" != "200" ]]; do sleep 1; done
#         curl -XPUT "$ES_URL/_template/$TEMPLATE_NAME" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"index_patterns":['\""$INDEX_PATTERN"\"'],"settings":{"number_of_shards":'$SHARD_COUNT',"number_of_replicas":'$REPLICA_COUNT'}}'

sysctlInitContainer:
  enabled: true

keystore: []

networkPolicy:
  ## Enable creation of NetworkPolicy resources. Only Ingress traffic is filtered for now.
  ## In order for a Pod to access Elasticsearch, it needs to have the following label:
  ## {{ template "uname" . }}-client: "true"
  ## Example for default configuration to access HTTP port:
  ## elasticsearch-master-http-client: "true"
  ## Example for default configuration to access transport port:
  ## elasticsearch-master-transport-client: "true"

  http:
    enabled: false
    ## if explicitNamespacesSelector is not set or set to {}, only client Pods being in the networkPolicy's namespace
    ## and matching all criteria can reach the DB.
    ## But sometimes, we want the Pods to be accessible to clients from other namespaces, in this case, we can use this
    ## parameter to select these namespaces
    ##
    # explicitNamespacesSelector:
    #   # Accept from namespaces with all those different rules (only from whitelisted Pods)
    #   matchLabels:
    #     role: frontend
    #   matchExpressions:
    #     - {key: role, operator: In, values: [frontend]}

    ## Additional NetworkPolicy Ingress "from" rules to set. Note that all rules are OR-ed.
    ##
    # additionalRules:
    #   - podSelector:
    #       matchLabels:
    #         role: frontend
    #   - podSelector:
    #       matchExpressions:
    #         - key: role
    #           operator: In
    #           values:
    #             - frontend

  transport:
    ## Note that all Elasticsearch Pods can talk to themselves using transport port even if enabled.
    enabled: false
    # explicitNamespacesSelector:
    #   matchLabels:
    #     role: frontend
    #   matchExpressions:
    #     - {key: role, operator: In, values: [frontend]}
    # additionalRules:
    #   - podSelector:
    #       matchLabels:
    #         role: frontend
    #   - podSelector:
    #       matchExpressions:
    #         - key: role
    #           operator: In
    #           values:
    #             - frontend

tests:
  enabled: true
```

Comment: Can you please share your `values.yaml` file?

Comment: Updated my question with the values.yaml file

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved after modifying the docker daemon configuration in the EKS worker node with ulimits (nproc) > 1024